# Manually cycling through VBA Code enters data into web, but clicking button does not

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2013 to log into a website and change data automatically.

Following Code works perfectly to open the website, enter the User Name and Password, "sign in", and open the next screen.

It should then populate two more boxes on the new screen, but it does not. It generates a RunTime Error saying an "Object is required".

But if I press "Debug" and "step through" from the error line, the Code runs perfectly!

```
Option Explicit

Sub EnterWeb()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Dim uRl As String
Dim UserN As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim PW As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim CoNum As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim AuthCode As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElement

Dim SUBMIT As Object 'MSHTML.IHTMLElement

'STAGE 1 - LOG INTO THE WEBSITE

'Set the website
    uRl = "WEBSITE NAME GOES HERE"

    With IE
    .navigate uRl
    .Visible = True
    End With

' loop until the page finishes loading
    Do While IE.Busy
    Loop

'Enter User name in "e-mail" textbox
    Set UserN = IE.document.getElementByID("email")
    If Not UserN Is Nothing Then
    UserN.Value = "TEXT GOES HERE"
    End If

'Enter Password in "Password" textbox
    Set PW = IE.document.getElementByID("seccode")
    If Not PW Is Nothing Then
    PW.Value = "TEXT GOES HERE"
    End If

'Sign in to site

Dim Item As Object

Set Item = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button positive regular")
    Item.Item(0).Click

'STAGE 2 -ENTER DETAILS ON NEXT PAGE

'Enter in First textbox
'THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS.
'RUNNING MACRO AUTOMATICALLY GENERATES A RUNTIME ERROR 424 - "OBJECT REQUIRED"
'BUT STEPPING THROUGH USING F8 IT RUNS PERFECTLY
    Set CoNum = IE.document.getElementByID("PUTS ID HERE") 
    If Not CoNum Is Nothing Then
    CoNum.Value = "PUTS VALUE HERE"
    End If

'Enter Code in textbox
    Set AuthCode = IE.document.getElementByID("PUTS CODE HERE")
    If Not AuthCode Is Nothing Then
    AuthCode.Value = "PUTS TEXT HERE"
    End If

End Sub
```

All suggestions received gratefully

Ochimus

Comment: If it works in Debug but not when run straight through, then you likely have a timing issue.  You might need to wait for some event on the page to complete.  For example you don't wait after clicking the button just before stage 2.  You need to wait *every time* you navigate.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the wait period to include the `.readtState` and allow processing through the message queue pump rather than locking it up.

```
Do While IE.Busy or ie.readystate <> 4  'READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
  doevents
Loop
```

You also aren't waiting after you 'click'. Put another of these after the `.Click` and before you start trying to `Set` objects.

That should ensure that you receive the standard page. If dynamic content is being delivered that has not arrived by the time both of those conditions are met, there are other methods to implement.

Comment: @tim, Many thanks for seeing the issue, Now works smoothly, but doubtless there will be other challenges further down the process!